# How to make layer from object immediately in illustrator cc?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, layers, icon

I was wondered if I can make a layer from selected object in illustrator directly?

instead of creating a new layer then grab the 'path' from the previous layer to make it a new layer.

any shortcut related to this?

Comment: You can create an action for it. It will make your work easier.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use a couple of shortcuts.

1) Select the object

2) Ctrl + L or Cmd + L for a new layer

3) Ctrl + X or Cmd + X to cut the object

4) Go to new layer, Ctrl + F or Cmd + F to paste in front. Or choose one of the other pasting methods.

Not sure if there is a faster method for what you're trying to do.